# django dumpdata => load on heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to load the data from my sqlite database to heroku postgres but it is not working.

First I ran:

```
manage.py dumpdata --indent 1 > data.json
```

and then I tried to upload it to heroku with (after I committed the file to heroku):

```
heroku run python manage.py loaddata data.json
```

but it just didn't work...

it gave me errors:

```
Running `python manage.py loaddata data.json` attached to terminal... up, run.92
01
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/_
_init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/_
_init__.py", line 377, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/b
ase.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/b
ase.py", line 338, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/c
ommands/loaddata.py", line 61, in handle
self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/c
ommands/loaddata.py", line 91, in loaddata
self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/c
ommands/loaddata.py", line 148, in load_label
obj.save(using=self.using)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/
base.py", line 173, in save
models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py
", line 617, in save_base
updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, upda
te_fields)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/django/db/models/base.py
", line 679, in _save_table
forced_update)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py
", line 723, in _do_update
return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.p
y", line 600, in _update
return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/com
piler.py", line 1004, in execute_sql
cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/com
piler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils
.py", line 65, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",     line 94, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils
.py", line 65, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Problem installing fixture '/app/data.json': C
ould not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=1): relation "django_content_type"     does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "django_content_type" SET "name" = 'log entry', "app_...
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys

Comment: I'm getting this with Django 1.9.2

Comment: I manually logged in and ran `python manage.py migrate` (it had already been run successfully!). Magically, it works. I don't understand why it needs to be run twice?!

Answer (score 3):

The end of the stacktrace has the key:

```
relation "django_content_type"     does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "django_content_type" SET "name" = 'log entry', "app_...
```

The table `django_content_type` does not exist.  Try running the migrations:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

or, if you are using an old version:

```
heroku run python manage.py setupdb
```

Comment: I've run both `makemigrations` and `migrate` before running `loaddata`, and it still triggers the issue. It works locally with SQLite.

Comment: You need to run ``python manage.py makemigrations`` locally, commit the new migrations, and push them to heroku. You also need any fixtures committed to the repo.  Then you can run ``heroku run python manage.py migrate`` to migrate the Heroku database, and ``loaddata`` to load fixtures.  ``heroku run X`` commands can't create files, they can only work with files already committed and pushed.